# JS - Pass an array of objects to a new window

Tags: javascript, java, window.open

I have an ajax request that returns an array of objects, I need to return them on another page for printing. But I do not know how to pass this array of objects to another tab or page.

```
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "atualizeOrder",
         data: JSON.stringify(ordens),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(list) {
             console.log(list);


          var printWindow = window.open( '/erp/index/test');
          printWindow.document.write(list);
          printWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
              printWindow.print();
              printWindow.close();
          }, true);



         }
    });
```

Comment: What does your code currently do?

Comment: return a new window with this:  [object Object]

Comment: Try using `printWindow.document.write(JSON.stringify(list));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your array in your child window:

```
printWindow.myList = list;
```

Then it will be accessible in any JavaScript code executed inside the child window as a global variable `myList`

You can also pre-render the lis in the parent window and append the resulting HTML to the child window, you can do this in jQuery or a template engine (like Mustache)

```
var renderedListHTML = Mustache.render("HTML TEMPLATE HERE", list);
printWindow.document.write(renderedListHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for asking, but how can I manipulate the variable myList? When I try to access this variable on a new page it is undefined

Comment: In your erp/index/test page, just add a script and then it will be accessible as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var printWindow = window.open('/erp/index/test');
printWindow.list = list;
```

Here "list" becomes a property of the new window object, so you can manipulate it quite easily.